# Why doesn't `torsocks git clone https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning.git` work?

Tags: torsocks

`torsocks git clone https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning.git`
does not work and gives me:

```
Cloning into 'lightning'...
1643140279 PERROR torsocks[51452]: socks5 libc connect: Connection refused (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:202)
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com
```

as I'm using a custom TorSocks port I also tried `torsocks -P <integer-not-to-be-doxxed> git clone https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning.git` and got

```
Cloning into 'lightning'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 84494, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (997/997), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (529/529), done.
remote: Total 84494 (delta 581), reused 724 (delta 456), pack-reused 83497
Receiving objects: 100% (84494/84494), 44.87 MiB | 1.67 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (64620/64620), done.
1643175331 ERROR torsocks[136753]: Unable to resolve. Status reply: 4 (in socks5_recv_resolve_reply() at socks5.c:677)
```

Comparing with the directory cloned without torsocks by running `diff -r lightning /home/john/lightning` gives me some differences in files whose importance is not known to me:

```
Binary files lightning/.git/index and /home/john/lightning/.git/index differ
diff -r lightning/.git/logs/HEAD /home/john/lightning/.git/logs/HEAD
1c1
< 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 4dafeede5c81d1ba7626480083ad4bb6716a5f70 john <john@john-ONE-AMD-M4.(none)> 1643175525 +0100 clone: from https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning.git
---
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 4dafeede5c81d1ba7626480083ad4bb6716a5f70 john <john@john-ONE-AMD-M4.(none)> 1643175331 +0100 clone: from https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning.git
diff -r lightning/.git/logs/refs/heads/master /home/john/lightning/.git/logs/refs/heads/master
1c1
< 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 4dafeede5c81d1ba7626480083ad4bb6716a5f70 john <john@john-ONE-AMD-M4.(none)> 1643175525 +0100 clone: from https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning.git
---
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 4dafeede5c81d1ba7626480083ad4bb6716a5f70 john <john@john-ONE-AMD-M4.(none)> 1643175331 +0100 clone: from https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning.git
diff -r lightning/.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD /home/john/lightning/.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
1c1
< 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 4dafeede5c81d1ba7626480083ad4bb6716a5f70 john <john@john-ONE-AMD-M4.(none)> 1643175525 +0100 clone: from https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning.git
---
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 4dafeede5c81d1ba7626480083ad4bb6716a5f70 john <john@john-ONE-AMD-M4.(none)> 1643175331 +0100 clone: from https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning.git
Only in lightning/.git/objects/pack: pack-586d5b1c27e10e245ee727dce48e1417cb4d35c5.idx
Only in lightning/.git/objects/pack: pack-586d5b1c27e10e245ee727dce48e1417cb4d35c5.pack
Only in /home/john/lightning/.git/objects/pack: pack-e0c04dcbc0385bf98b24b9435bc415b19953ac10.idx
Only in /home/john/lightning/.git/objects/pack: pack-e0c04dcbc0385bf98b24b9435bc415b19953ac10.pack
```

It used to work some time ago, sadly not anymore. Why doesn't it work?
How might I clone the repo over Tor?

Comment: @Prayank Appending `VirtualAddrNetwork 192.168.0.0/16` in `etc/tor/torrc` has not helped. I'm using a nonstandard TorSocks port, specifying it with `-P <integer>` seems to help, I still get `1643175331 ERROR torsocks[136753]: Unable to resolve. Status reply: 4 (in socks5_recv_resolve_reply() at socks5.c:677)`, though.

Comment: Sorry I cannot help. Ask for help from Pieter Wuille or Moderators.

Comment: This is a question more about tor than it is about anything Bitcoin specific, so it will be migrated to the Tor stackexchange.

Comment: I can successfully download that git repo using torsocks. Try running it with the `--debug` flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's how the Git works - you need to set Git socks proxy like that:

`git config --global http.proxy 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050'`

and to unset it:
`git config --global --unset http.proxy`

Use `http.proxy` or `https.proxy` for names. That's good to make one-liner to make *any* nested calls for Git work, i.e. in a complex shell scripts, without touching a line.

And another workaround is using *just for the one line* is to use `ALL_PROXY` variable like that:
`ALL_PROXY=socks5://127.0.0.1:9050 git clone xxxxxx` .

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've set Git socks proxy with:
`git config --global https.proxy 'socks5://127.0.0.1:port-of-my-choice-not-to-be-doxxed'`
Now that it is configured, as evidenced in my `~/.gitconfig`, may I skip the `torsocks` command 
when cloning the repo and will it still be cloned over tor? Like so `git clone https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning.git`?

Comment: just one **more** thing to know: `socks5` will resolve DNS through **your local** resolver, and `socks5h` in the protocol specification name will use remote resolver - just in case. Use the thing that fits your particular case. And - yes - as the proxy is set - no need to use neither `torsocks`, nor `proxychains` e.t.c. - it is already set in git's configuration files and used automatically. If you're about to use ALL_PROXY - keep in mind that some shell scripts and nested calls can fail and go directly.